# git merge with renames in one branch

Tags: git

I have two branches. In one branch I *only* renamed files with `git mv`. In another branch some of those same files were modified. I would like to merge the latter branch into the former. I would think that since git knows about the rename operation this would not be a problem, yet this is not what I am seeing

Here is a scaled down experiment demonstrating the issue:

```
/tmp/gittest λ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/gittest/.git/
/tmp/gittest:no-branch*? λ touch foo
/tmp/gittest:no-branch*? λ git add foo
/tmp/gittest:no-branch*? λ git commit -m initial
[main (root-commit) 532197b] initial
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
/tmp/gittest:main? λ git checkout -b moved
Switched to a new branch 'moved'
/tmp/gittest:moved? λ git mv foo foo.moved
/tmp/gittest:moved*? λ git commit -m 'move it'
[moved 384b27d] move it
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename foo => foo.moved (100%)
/tmp/gittest:moved? λ git checkout main
Switched to branch 'main'
/tmp/gittest:main? λ ls
foo
/tmp/gittest:main? λ echo "v2" > foo
/tmp/gittest:main*? λ git add foo
/tmp/gittest:main*? λ git commit -m 'changed'
[main 25c98d1] changed
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
/tmp/gittest:main? λ git checkout moved
Switched to branch 'moved'
/tmp/gittest:moved? λ ls
foo.moved
/tmp/gittest:moved? λ git merge main
CONFLICT (modify/delete): foo deleted in HEAD and modified in main. Version main of foo left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I get a similar result with rebase.

I am aware that git stores tree states not diffs, but I thought the fact that git explicitly knew about the rename would help with that.

What is going on and what is the correct approach here?

Comment: This wouldn't be my first choice (or maybe not even my second), but in a pinch you could also rename the files on the branch to be merged in with a new commit on that branch, and then do the merge. If those are the only files that have conflicts then you could even use `merge -X theirs` to automate the resolution in one shot.

Comment: @TTT that's a really good idea actually! I've got tens of thousands of files moved but fortunately was forward-thinking enough to do it literate-programming style within emacs so I actually have it all available as a script. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Since you seemed to like it more than I expected, I added it as an answer. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you "told" Git about the rename, it still doesn't "know".  At least, it doesn't know from the `git mv` command.

The working tree's internal state after `git mv a.txt b.txt` is more or less the same as if you had done:

```
$ mv a.txt b.txt
$ git rm --cached a.txt
$ git add b.txt
```

The fact that you used `git mv` isn't recorded anywhere and doesn't influence Git's operation.

The default merge strategy, either `recursive` on older versions of Git or its newer cousin `ort` on newer versions, does attempt to do rename detection, but it does this based on similarities of deleted and added files, not by "remembering" that you did a `git mv` at some time in the past.

Fortunately, `recursive`/`ort` should do this rename detection on a commit by commit basis, so if you have a commit where a bunch of files were renamed with no modifications, the similarity index for these files will be 100%, and the operation will always be detected as a rename.  The resulting merge should always be able to successfully merge the rename operations from one branch with modifications made on another branch to yield the desired result.

Unfortunately, there is one exception.  Empty files always have similarity index 0% when compared to any other file.  This is to prevent detecting unrelated empty file deletions and additions as renames.  That's why your test case fails.  If you replace the `touch foo` with `echo 'a' >foo` so the initial `foo` is non-empty, your test case will merge fine.  The `recursive` merge strategy will see the rename (at 100% similarity) on the `moved` branch and the modifications on the `main` branch and merge the rename and the modification into a correct final result.

The fact that you are experiencing this problem outside of your test case is odd, assuming you are renaming non-empty files.  Double-check that there is a commit that renames the files in question with no modification (or at least high enough similarity to be recognized as a rename -- `git diff` or `git show` on the commit can help determine this).  Also, I see that you have modified your Git configuration to make `main` instead of `master` your default branch.  Make sure you haven't made a similar configuration change to set your default merge strategy to something other than `recursive`/`ort`.

If you discover that the commit containing the renames *did* include some modifications that resulted in the files being too dissimilar to be identified as renames, you can modify the similarity threshold from its default of 50% in the merge command.  For example:

```
git merge -X find-renames=40% main
```

Comment: hmm...interesting. Our github *is* set to "squash and merge" as a PR merge strategy. I don't "think" that would be a problem given what you said, but its also no end of problems in general...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer this is off topic, but regarding squash merge, it's fine to use for feature branches into a shared target branch, but you don't want to use squash merge when the source branch is a long-lived shared branch. (e.g. in Git Flow, don't squash merge when merging `main` into `develop`, `release` into `main`, etc.)

Comment: It looks like as of [fairly recently](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-12-merge-commits-now-created-using-the-merge-ort-strategy/) GitHub has switched from `recursive` to `ort` as its default merge strategy.  My Git is too old to support `ort`, but I assume it should work equally well with renames, and I agree it's not clear why squashing should cause problems here.  Maybe try fetching the offending branches, simulate your own squash, and see if you can duplicate the failure on a local version of Git with the `ort` strategy.

Comment: @TTT its what we have but I'm honestly not even ok with it even on feature branches. The thing is that the github diff screen doesn't work the same way as `git diff` does locally (where it just compares file contents). It instead takes all commits that are in source but not in target and aggregates those. So if you have `main > branch1 > branch2` and you merge `branch1 ` into `main` and then try to merge `branch2` in, since you've squashed those `branch1` commits, your PR diff is going to be a mess showing code that already got merged

Comment: @GeorgeMauer agreed! Note it isn't inherently a problem with squashing, but the re-writing of IDs in general. That same issue also happens if you rebase `branch1`, which I personally like having that option. Some would consider `main > branch1 > branch2` an anti-pattern in general, for the reason you stated. Perhaps the trick would be to teach everyone how to do a `rebase` with the `--onto` option anytime they branch off of anything other than `main`. If they know how to (and when to) `rebase --onto` after `branch1` is merged the PR will be clean once again. (We went on a tangent here...)

Comment: Very small files get wildly-swingy similarity index values so that rename detection doesn't work well for them. (This is because the detection works on up-to-64-character chunklets from lines and then computes a ratio based on the file size; dividing by a small file size amplifies small changes in the matching-chunklets counts.) Rename detection tends to work a lot better for files that are at least 50 or so lines long...

Comment: @torek good thing that most of our files are hundreds and thousands of lines long then . But yeah, great info, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to at least try [K. A. Buhr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73737225/184546) first.

This wouldn't be my first choice (or maybe not even my second), but in a pinch you could also rename the files on the branch to be merged in with a new commit on that branch, and then do the merge. If those are the only files that have conflicts then you could even use `merge -X theirs` to automate the resolution in one shot.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think his answer is the correct one for the question I asked, but this is what's going to help my current situation more

Answer (score 0):

Good evening!

The **moved** branch refers to some *commit* and this *commit* refers to a *tree* and this *tree* doesn't refer to a valid *blob*, it refers to a *blob* for **foo.moved** filename (not **foo**)

Look at example in my case:

```
stack -> git lg

* ae9ca46 (master) changed
| * af7a220 (HEAD, moved) move it
|/
* a02287a initial



stack -> git cat-file -p af7a220
tree 7e4a4fd9f5c65d2dce07ff9050d28247bf9ce8f3
parent a02287a28f210498c286ae158b07ecb53a4fc94d
author nodorgrom <nodorgrom@gmail.com> 1663272773 +0300
committer nodorgrom <nodorgrom@gmail.com> 1663272773 +0300

move it



stack -> git cat-file -p 7e4a4fd9f5c65d2dce07ff9050d28247bf9ce8f3
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    foo.moved
```